How to replace a value inside a MultiValueMap<String, List<?>> in Java?
I am using org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.
As a parameter I am passed a MultiValueMap<String, List<?>> multimap. My example here won't utilize having multiple values per each key, but it's used in my other code so I have to keep it as a MultiValueMap and not a regular Map. For this example, my multivaluemap just looks like a regular map:
{
"var1"=["to replace"], 
"var2"=["hey"]
}

I want to replace the list for var1.
My code looks like this:
String str = "a new string";
multimap.set("var1", Collections.singletonList(str));
System.out.println(multimap.get("var1");
System.out.println(multimap.get("var2");

So getting and printing "var2" returns how I want it to because I never replaced it, printing: [hey]
But getting "var1" immediately after, prints out this: [[a new string]]
This makes any of my other code that uses this map not work. I think what I'm doing right now is incorrectly replacing the original string value with a list? But if I simply do multimap.set("var1", str); it will not run.
How do I set the value for "var1" in the MultiValueMap so that it is a List rather than a List of Lists?

Have you tried multimap.set("var1",str);

I tried that and it does not run. It gives me the error that the required type is List<?>, not String.

It sounds like what you want is a MultiValueMap<String, String>, not a MultiValueMap<String, List<?>>.

I can't change the type within the MultiValueMaps unfortunately. I'm working within the confines of old code. I'm not sure how they input these String values into the MultiValuemap either because the code that passes it to my class uses @RequestParam to insert the keys and values.

Did you try replace?
replace(K key,  V oldValue,  V newValue)
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replace(K,V,V)

If you can't change the type, then there is no way to "set the value for var1 in the MultiValueMap so that it is a List rather than a List of Lists."  The MultiValueMap contains lists of lists, and there's nothing you can do about that.

@RanAbitbul this worked for me! I added an edit to my question saying as such, but if you post an answer I will mark that as solved

According to Spring framework's MultiValueMap docs:

void set(K key,
@Nullable
V value)
Set the given single value under the given key.

Meaning adds the value to the existing key's value.
Since MultiValueMap inherits from java.util.Map, you can use the replace method - replace(K key,  V oldValue,  V newValue).

If you look at
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html
you can read, that the second generic parameter of that MultiValueMap (V) is the generic type of a List in the parent interface.
With MultiValueMap<String, List<?>> multimap what you define for the value type of the map, is a List of Lists, hence you get [[a new string]], indicating a List (of any ?) in a List.
Anyway, you should post a complete example of code.
